# How to make a citizen take a certain job

Tags: tropico-4

I want to make a certain citizen take the open doctor job at a clinic, in which I fire her at her current job (farmer), but she always goes to being a teamster/farmer. I checked her education and she qualifies (college) but she wont go become a doctor at the clinic. I actually have two clinics (3/4 slots open). Clinic salary is also > than teamster/farmer salary. I wish there is a way to "drag" citizens to open work slots at certain buildings (think: dragging actors in the game The Movies). Or is there a way of doing this and I just havnt encountered it yet? Also, if there are no ways of doing this, does location of current house of the citizen affect her job choice?

Comment: Location of the house does certainly influence it, since Tropicans always take a job close to their home. You can see that if you delete houses next to a farm with no others in the vicinity, they will start building shags, even though there are enough free housing positions.

Answer (score 5):

Clinics/Hospitals, require *College educated **Men***, to fill their open job slots. Certain jobs in Tropico have gender requirements make sure you read what is required in the job description in the building details pane.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Sam is spot on - Tropico makes it technically impossible to have a women be a doctor.

In general, there is no way to force your people to take certain jobs. You can only influence their decision.

But just slightly higher salary is far from enough.

- Salary has to be noticably higher
- Work and home should to be close together
- The area should be nice

The job quality indicator can be raised a lot by offering very high salaries. Try to increase by more than just a couple dollars, and work on the other points, and the citizen will certainly go for it after some time.